# Why the the puts in my_strcpy function is not printing the value in the below given code?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

The puts in my_strcpy() function should also print according to me but why it is not printing, I am not able to understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>

void my_strcpy(char *source,char *destination);

int main()
{
  char strA[]="\nMy Name is Jagdeep\n";
  char strB[30];
  char *pA,*pB;
  pA=strA;
  pB=strB;
  my_strcpy(pA,pB);
  puts(pA);
  //puts(strB);

  return 0;
}


//function to copy strings 


void my_strcpy(char *source,char *destination)
{
  while(*source!='\0')
  {
    *destination++=*source++;
  }
  *destination='\0';
  cout<<"\t You are in str_mycopy";
  puts(destination);

}
```

The output by above code is :

```
You are in strmycopy

My Name is Jagdeep
```

Comment: I am beginner please do not vote my questions down...

Comment: Edit your question. On SO blocks of code should be marked with 4-spaces indention.

Comment: While not your problem, you should not mix stdio functions (like `puts`) with iostreams. Use one or the other.

Comment: @citxx: Thanks for making changes to understand the code in better way.

Answer (score 4):

You are changing `destination`. By the time you call `puts`, `destination` no longer points where you expect. It points to the end of the string, to a `\0`.

Try this:

```
char *original = destination;

/* while etc. */

puts(original);
```

Comment: if you remove the comments from puts(strB),it is printing the value then it should have also not printed.

Comment: @jagdeep: No, your function's `destination` parameter is not the same variable as `pB` - `destination` is a *copy* of `pB`. `pB` maintains its value across function calls.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `my_strcpy` the local variable `destination` is changed and points to the end of the string when `puts(destination)` executes. Thus it outputs nothing.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
But if you remove the comments from puts(strB),it is printing the value then it should have also not printed

Comment: @jagdeep: `destination` is the local variable in your function. When `strB` is passed to `my_strcpy` its value (address) is copied to `destination` variable. Henceforth any changes of `destination` doesn't affect `strB`.

Comment: But Destination is a pointer variable so changes should be reflected.

Comment: @jagdeep: Don't mix up the value of the pointer variable itself and the content of the memory where it points to. Any changes in that memory where are, of course, reflected. But the value of a pointer variable (address, number of memory cell in fact) won't be changed.